# creating html tab pages?

Tags: html

if i were to create tab pages in HTML, what 'container' so i need to produce multiple times for each 'page'? I was just going to adjust the 'visible' property (whichever one doesnt take up layout space when unselected) when the button is clicked.

Comment: I understand what you want but I don't understand what you are trying to tell...

Comment: I want to be able to click on a button and show a different frame per button?

Comment: If you dont want to use javascript, it can be done by css3
http://carsonified.com/blog/dev/stay-on-target/

Comment: @Codler's link has disappeared, here it is on [archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20100202060533/http://carsonified.com/blog/dev/stay-on-target/). Reader beware, :target is [not supported in IE](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html) until version 9, although there is a [poyfill](http://selectivizr.com).

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the jQuery UL Tabs: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use a bit of JavaScript to achieve this, jQuery will be your easiest option, check out the [jQuery UI tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/), this is what you need.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Comment: "a bit of JavaScript": you mean jQuery + jQuery UI = 70k??? little right...

Comment: Yeah? And if you get them from a CDN they'll probably be cached from another site, if you'd like to suggest a different method then feel free.

Comment: it sounds good except it's not true - http://bit.ly/9G5sGX

Comment: But still what's your point? He asked for a solution to his problem and he got one?

Answer (score 1):

You can create this pages with using CSS easily.

Here sample examples

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/item/css-tabs-menu

http://www.alvit.de/css-showcase/css-navigation-techniques-showcase.php

There are many tools to create tab menus.

http://www.tabsgenerator.com/